# Ada image attribute displaying a negative value for an unsigned type

Tags: attributes, ada

Given,

```
type X is new Integer range 0 .. (2 ** 31) - 1 ;
…
Y : X;
```

I'm using Ada attribute `X'Image(Y)` to display a value of an unsigned type, but it displays a signed value. Is it a limitation of this attribute or is there an issue?

Comment: What is X ? What is Y ? Please provide more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
type x is new Integer range 0 .. (2**31) - 1;
```

defines a derived type.

According to the Ada Reference Manual section 3.4

> A derived_type_definition defines a derived type (and its first
> subtype) whose characteristics are derived from those of a parent
> type, and possibly from progenitor types.
>
> A class of types is a set of types that is closed under derivation;
> that is, if the parent or a progenitor type of a derived type belongs
> to a class, then so does the derived type. By saying that a particular
> group of types forms a class, we are saying that all derivatives of a
> type in the set inherit the characteristics that define that set. The
> more general term category of types is used for a set of types whose
> defining characteristics are not necessarily inherited by derivatives;
> for example, limited, abstract, and interface are all categories of
> types, but not classes of types.

Thus, what you have defined is not an unsigned type. It is a signed type with a minimum value of 0, but it still retains the sign bit inherited from Integer.

The proper way to define an unsigned integer type is

```
type X is range 0 .. (2**31) - 1;
```

If you want a full 32-bit unsigned integer you would define

```
type X is range 0 .. (2**32) - 1;
```

Comment: The proper way to define an unsigned type is, for example, `type U is mod 2 ** 32;`. See package `Interfaces`.